# What is returned from Mongoose query that finds no matches?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm a little confused reading the Mongoose documentation.

If I run a query in mongoose which matches no documents in the collection, what are the values of `err` and `results` in the callback function `callback(err, results)`? I just don't know what Mongoose considers an "error". As a mathematician, returning the empty set (i.e. `results` array empty) seems perfectly valid and shouldn't be an "error" - the query executed fine, there was just no matching documents. On the other hand, some may consider it an "error". From mongoose docs, either:

1. `err` = null, `results` = []
2. `err` = null, `results` = null
3. `err` = error document, `results` = null

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It depends on the query. If it is a `find`, then `results == []`. If it is a `findOne`, then `results == null`. No errors if everything else is ok.

Comment: Guess there is three options ;)

Comment: So, in `find` its case 1, in `findOne` its case 2?

Comment: You can use it like `var query = Model.find();` or `var query = Model.findOne();` Later edit: i just saw your edit, indeed, 3 options :) You got the cases right.

Comment: What are the results if you use .populate?

Answer (score 10):

If conditions were valid but no matches were found:

- `find`: `err` is `null`, `result` is `[]`
- `findOne` and `findById`: `err` is `null`, `result` is `null`

However, if some condition was invalid (e.g. field is `string` but you pass an `object`, or you pass an invalid `_id`)

For all three: `err` is `{..}`, `result` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

If using `.find()`,
The handy way would be

```
models.<your collection name>.find({ _id: `your input` }).then(data => {
    if (data.length == 0) return // throw your error to the console;
});
```